# Unable to Import Spreadsheet as list

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I try to the Import Spreadsheet app in SharePoint 2013 I get the following errors.

[image: First Error I get]

[image: Second Error I get]

Comment: try removing all macros from the workbook and importing again

Comment: I first have to learn what macros is an excel workbook is. :)

Comment: Is Macros a way to record Excel procedures in order to save time?

Comment: Yes, that second image looks to be an excel macro in your workbook

Comment: So SharePoint 2013 will allow uploading of Excel sheets as a default option? Nothing has to be done from the preferences or back end of SharePoint to allow that to happen?

Comment: Yes, this has been around for a while, I wouldn't recommend it though as you have no control over how your data is defined by the process, most everything gets converted to single line of text. best to create the list and copy the data over in quick edit mode